# WPF in WinForms: blocked on Dispatcher.Invoke although UI thread alive

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface, freeze

We have a WPF control embedded in a WinForms control which is in turn exposed as an ActiveX control. This ActiveX is finally used in a C++ application developped by a third party.

At some point, the ActiveX control's UI becomes frozen, whereas the rest of the C++ application runs fine. After some debugging, I noticed that the WPF control was blocked on every call of Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke. However, the WinForms control processes its calls of Control.Invoke just fine. Whenever I pause the debugger, I can see that the UI thread is doing some work in the C++ application, but doesn't seem to be blocked or waiting for anything. It's as if the UI thread was suddenly and inexplicably refusing to execute the WPF delegates.

The WPF control sometimes enters this state when the C++ application monopolizes the UI thread for an extended period of time (a few minutes). The first thing I would do would be to use a different thread for such a time-consuming task, but as I already said, I'm not responsible for what the C++ application is doing. Anyway, this is no reason for my WPF control to behave in such a way. I have no idea how to solve this problem though; any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest running the MS Debug Diagnostics Tool - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2580960.

We have had great results using this to identify COM interop blocking issues, which were in our case down to a pending COM finalizer blocking garbage collection. You can run it in various modes, but when run with the .NET analysis it will highlight any issues with the finalizer queue etc. It's a little clunky to run, but the info it gives you is gold.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `Invoke` is that it's acts like a multi-threaded invocation; but it's really not, `Invoke` is blocking--you're still only letting one thread at a time.  `Invoke` really just makes sure an action is executed on the UI thread.  This is done by forcing a message into a message pump and executing it that way.  That action might be blocked on something that the thread calling `Invoke` needs to do to let the action continue.
For example:

```
lock(someLock)
{
    dispatcher.Invoke(SomeMethod);
}

//...

public void SomeMethod()
{
  lock(someLock)
  {
  //... do some work here
  }
}
```

In this example, `Invoke` is blocked invoking `SomeMethod` while holding a lock.  But, `SomeMethod` wants the same `lock` so it's blocked waiting for the `lock`.  You have a deadlock.

I would suggest using `BeginInvoke` instead.

I don't know for sure if that's your problem because you haven't provided any code; but that's a *very* common problem with `Invoke`.  There's usually no reason to need `Invoke`; if you think there is a need, that's usually an indication of a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Peter. In your example, the main thread would be blocked on the the lock in SomeMethod. In my case, it is not blocked on anything; there is really no reason why I should be stuck on an Invoke. And as I said, the Invokes in WinForm on the same thread work just fine. It's apparently the WPF Dispatcher that for some reason is not responding anymore.

Comment: @odsh Yes, that is simply an example of where you can get a deadlock by using `Invoke` instead of `BeginInvoke`--although with WinForms and not WPF.  The same applies to `Dispatcher.Invoke`/`BeginInvoke`.  Framework methods lock in many places that you don't know about and can't control--leading you to a similar situation.  Did you try using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` instead?

Comment: I cannot afford to replace all Invokes with BeginInvokes in my application; sometimes the call has to be synchronous. Anyway, I don't think there is a deadlock, or else the main thread would be blocked - which he isn't. If, as you suggest, a framework method is blocked somewhere, I would like to understand why and correct the problem. Discarding the Invokes because they could randomly cause deadlocks in places I don't know about is not a solution in my case.